# Using SQL script through ssh fails, but not when it is started directly on the Host

Tags: mysql, docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have configured a Jenkins Job and my Pipeline looks like this:

```
        stage ('Preparing SQL Database'){
        steps{
            //Starting MYSQL Image
            sh '(sudo sshpass -p "PASSWORD" ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no  $user@$host "sudo docker run --name nameofthecontainer -p 13306:3306 -d mysql:mysql")'

            sh '(sudo sshpass -p "PASSWORD" ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no  $user@host "/opt/docker/dockerdeployment/databasescript.sh")'
        }
```

My databasescript.sh looks like this (Just importing an SQL-DUMP):

```
sudo docker exec -i nameofthecontainer  /usr/bin/mysql -u $MYSQLUSER -pPassword $MYSQLOPTIONS $MYSQLDB -e "DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS ${MYSQLDB};CREATE DATABASE ${MYSQLDB} DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT COLLATE utf8_general_ci; commit;"
sudo docker exec -i nameofthecontainer  /usr/bin/mysql -u $MYSQLUSER -pPassword $MYSQLOPTIONS $MYSQLDB < /srv/Dump.sql

done
```

When I execute the Script directly on the host, it succeed. 
But when I try to Run the Jenkins-Job (who is executing this databasescript over ssh) there are these ERROR Message(s):

```
ERROR 2013 (HY000): Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 0
(...)
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved it. The problem was, that the mysql-container was not ready to accept connections when the second step was executed. I fixed it with a sleep command between the two steps.